# Image is not getting displayed from a URL- picasso+okhttp+retrofit Android

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to use Picasso library to load and cache images from the server.The image does not load and the view is blank.I doubt it has got to do with some conflicts in my existing libraries.Here is my libs folder.[image]

Could some one help? Previously I was getting an error that picasso needs a specific version of okhttp and okhttpurlconnection.After adding those jars that error is resolved but the image still doesnot get displayed.

Here is my code

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(arg0.get(1).getResult2().get(0).getThumbnail()).into(totd_image);
```

The image URL is valid.

Comment: You need to add it in your build.gradle as a dependency. something like this: `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'` also, I don't think Picasso needs any extra libraries. BTW, your screenshot of libs folder is missing.

Comment: The image is visible to me..Will edit it again.I am using Eclipse.. So no gradle support..

Comment: For eclipse, see the [Picasso website](http://square.github.io/picasso/) , under the downloads / maven section

Comment: I have added the jar into libs folder and added it to build path..

Comment: Try without the specific versions okhttp. What error did it give without these specific versions?

Comment: I had not added okhttp-urlconnection previously.. which is required for picasso to work..This was the previous error java.lang.RuntimeException: Picasso detected an unsupported OkHttp on the classpath.
To use OkHttp with this version of Picasso, you'll need:
1. com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0 (or newer)
2. com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0 (or newer)

Comment: Are you where it's required for Picasso to work? Also are you using the same versions of okhttp and okhttpurlconnection ?

Comment: I am using the same version. 2.2.0

Comment: That error tells you exactly what you need. Do you have exactly those libraries?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71751/discussion-between-prasanna-aarthi-and-jonascz).

Answer (score 0):

Picasso only loads and displays images from secure locations using 
`HTTPS` **NOT** `HTTP`